# Bizarre encoding of umlaute (äöü)

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm currently making a school project, where I need to download data from a website (by crawling) and process/display it in an app for Android. The downloaded data often contains letters like `ä`, which can be displayed perfectly in a `TextView` without any doubt.

Sometimes, the data that I receive has gaps, which my parser fills after downloading it. Instead of displaying `textThatContainsÄ`, it displays `&nbsp;`. Easy fix:

```
String data = downloadFromServer();

// Fill the gap
data = data.replace("&nbsp;", textThatContainsÄ);
```

The output as expected:

```
Output: [..]ä[..]
```

The logic I wrote above was packaged into a `.jar` and imported into my Android app. The data I downloaded is not affected in any way in the Android app because of encapsulation.

Now comes the twist. If the downloaded data from the server does **NOT** originally contain `textThatContainsÄ` (so that my parser has to fill the gap) Android interprets it as `textThatContainsÃ¤`, which is clearly a `UTF-8` encoding problem, which is caused by treating the `UTF-8` bytes as `Windows-1252 (or ISO 8859-1)` bytes (Android interprets the text as 21 instead of 18 bytes (Text has size of 9)). This problem does not occur if the data originally contains the `ä`.

I don't know why the `ä` generated by java code creates encoding problems in Android.

Edit: Was caused by Gradle.

Comment: How is `textThatContainsÄ` defined? If it is `String textThatContainsÄ = "\\u00C4";` then everything should be fine, but if it is `String textThatContainsÄ = "Ä";` then you might be compiling the source code with the wrong character set. If source file is saved with UTF-8, be sure to explicitly tell compiler to use UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shot myself in the leg by using Gradle. After some research, I found out that Gradle normally does **NOT** compile `.java` files using `UTF-8` by default. So when I compiled the `.jar` it accidentally translated `ä` to `Ã¤` as I could see in the decompiled `.class` files.

By adding the code below, the whole problem was solved.

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```